# How can i "listen" external changes of database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mariadb

How can I catch database changes which are done by third-party applications in Laravel? Actually, when new data is inserted into the database by 3rd party application, I have to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't, at least from Laravel point of view by itself.

On relational databases you can create several triggers on tables you want to watch for changes and then make the stored procedure that is being called notifies Laravel in some way.

However, as you can see, it involves more parts from your application that Laravel itself.
Additionally, it has its own cons. For example, database have to *know* about the Laravel or *whatever* framework a third application is using.

I don't know if this solution could work for you, but it's the best option that I can give you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. You instead need the third party application to notify your Laravel application in some fashion that the changes have been made.

If the third party application supports webhooks that might be a viable approach. Or if it can push a notification to something like Redis, that might work too.

But it sounds like you're probably doing something that is a bad idea anyway. Two applications shouldn't really share a database except in quite limited circumstances.